# How can I find the longest word in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I have created a function to find the longest word in a text file and finding the longest word(s) in a text file that can  be made from 9 letters. I'm new to python and I'm creating a game similar to countdown.

I've created a function to find the longest word in the text file. What I want now is to create python code to find the longest word(s) that can be formed from the 9 letters.

Each letter can only be used once. So from 'qugteroda', I should get rag outed, outraged, out dare, out read, outrage,readout. I'm using python 3.3

my code looks like this:

```
def Words():
    qfile=open('dict.txt','r')
    long=''
    for line in qfile:
    if len(line)>len(long):
        long=line
    return long
```

Comment: So to clarify, you're asking how to make the longest possible word out of a list of letters? Can you repeat letters?

Comment: how to make the longest possible word or words. you can not repeat letters. Are you familiar with the game countdown.

Comment: You shouldn't use `long` as a variable name. That's also the name of a built-in function.

Comment: @omz incorrect.  the OP clearly specified they are using python3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to find the longest sorted combination from a set of letters that exist in your dictionary.

To do so, you'd use [itertools.combinations()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with a length equal to the length of your string. You'd check all of those combinations against the sorted dictionary, and if you don't find a match, decrease the combination length.

You also want to load the entire dictionary into a set to decrease search times. I've loaded the set of words into a dictionary, where the key is the sorted string, and the value is a list of words that have the same sorted representation.

Something like this:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

words = defaultdict(list)
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as qfile:
    for word in qfile:
        word = word.rstrip('\n').lower()
        words[''.join(sorted(word))].append(word)

def longest_anagram(term, words):
    search_length = len(term)
    term = sorted(term) # combinations maintains sort order
    while search_length > 0:
        for combo in itertools.combinations(term, search_length):
            search = ''.join(combo) # sort above means we dont need it here
            if search in words:
                return words[search]
        search_length -= 1
    return None

found = longest_anagram('qugteroda', words)
for w in found:
    print(w)
```

For completeness I should mention that this approach is appropriate for a search string of 18 letters or less. If you need to find the longest anagram out of a string of letters that is greater than 18, you're better off flipping the algorithm so you sort the dictionary words by length into a list. You'd then iterate through all the words and check to see if they exist in the input search string - much like @abarnert's answer.

Comment: I think you meant "to decrease search times". :)

Comment: @abarnert I sure did :P ta

Comment: At any rate, this way, you have to iterate through all 362880 (+181440+…) permutations to look them each up in a hash table. Iterating the dictionary ought to be an order of magnitude faster (considering that a dictionary is usually on the order of 36K words). And of course as the anagrams get longer, this gets even worse. (It's still definitely worth having this answer, because the OP should be thinking through exactly these questions.)

Comment: @abarnert If I was writing this for myself, I'd create a dictionary that keyed the sorted string and indexed into a list of matching items. Assuming of course that I'd be looking up more than one word at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Your current code returns the longest line in a text file, full stop.

If you want the longest line that's an anagram of some input string, you need to take an input string, and filter out the lines that aren't anagrams.

Since you specified that there are no repeat letters, the easiest way to checks whether two words are anagrams is to just check whether they each have the same set of letters. So:

```
def Words(inputletters):
    inputletters = set(inputletters)
    qfile=open('dict.txt','r')
    long=''
    for line in qfile:
        if set(line.strip()) == inputletters:
            if len(line)>len(long):
                long=line
    return long
```

If you're not looking for an exact match, but merely a *subset*, just replace the `==` with `.issubset`.

Or if by "you cannot repeat letters" you actually meant "you must repeat exactly the *same* letters in two strings for them to count as anagrams", that's simple too: instead of comparing the *set* of letters, compare a *sorted list* of letters:

```
def Words(inputletters):
    inputletters = sorted(inputletters)
    qfile=open('dict.txt','r')
    long=''
    for line in qfile:
        if sorted(line.strip()) == inputletters:
            if len(line)>len(long):
                long=line
    return long
```

And so on. Once you can define exactly what you're searching for, it's probably a trivial change to the data structure and/or the comparison.

I don't think this is a complete program for whatever it is you're intending, but it should hopefully be enough to either (a) get you pointed in the right direction, or (b) get you to clarify the problem a little better.

---

Meanwhile, there are a few other things you could improve:

First, you should always close files that you open (ideally using a `with` statement).

While we're at it, the usual Python coding standard (as encoded in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) suggests lowercase function names. And `long` isn't a great name for a variable—while it's no longer a type as of Python 3.0, it may confuse readers who've been using Python since 2.x (which, at this point, is still the majority).

More interestingly, like many simple `for` loops in Python, your entire loop could be replaced by using a chain of iterator-transforming calls. The result is usually more concise, faster, and harder to get wrong, and often more readable.

So, let's write another version that changes all of that, and also checks for a subset instead of a complete set:

```
def words(inputletters):
    inputletters = set(inputletters)
    with open('dict.txt') as qfile:
        words = map(str.strip, qfile)
        letters = map(set, words)
        matching = filter(inputletters.issubset, letters)
        longest = max(matching, key=len)
        return longest
```

Of course you can merge some of those calls together (or even turn the whole chain into a one-liner, but I think that might be pushing the bounds of readability), or rewrite them as generator expressions (which combine much more nicely—compare `(set(line.strip()) for line in qfile)` to `map(set, map(str.strip, file))` or `map(lambda line: set(line.strip()), qfile)`.

Comment: While the OP did say "you can not repeat letters", I think what the OP really meant was "you must respect multiplicity", i.e. if you only have one "e" you can't spell a word with two "e"s.  That's how most of these games work, including Countdown, the one [referenced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)#Letters_round)  by the OP: "Each letter may be used only as often as it appears in the selection."

Comment: @wim: Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment, that's exactly what the code does, and exactly what the OP asked for, so… what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @DSM: I tried to answer what the OP actually asked, rather than try to guess what he really wants. But yeah, that's a pretty obvious guess, and there are various other pretty likely possibilities. I'd edited the answer to show how easily the OP can change it to suit whatever he's actually trying to solve. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @abarnert OP didn't close their file but that doesn't mean you don't have to!

Comment: My point was that `if set(line.strip()) == inputletters:` would fire on some line like `mississippi` with the inputletters being just `set('pims')`, which by my interpretation of the question would be a bug.  I also think it's sloppy to copy and paste OPs code and not clean up obvious things such as python style conventions, dangling file handles, etc ...

Comment: @jamylak: OK, I'll add an addendum showing all the other things that should be fixed. (I usually do, but this one seemed so long already…)

Answer (score 0):

```
def longestWord(fileName):
    mx = 0
    op = open(fileName,'r')
    words = op.read().split()
    for i in words:
        if len(i) > mx:
            mx = len(i)
            word = i
            #return the longest word and its length
    return (mx,word)
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more information about your answer along with the code

Comment: Although your post might answer the question, it lacks some explaining text and documentation. Please edit your answer and provide some.